# Windows 10 .bat (.cmd) files and explorer file associations

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Have a directory C:\handle-special with files shown below (contents of files does not have lines starting with #).

test.handle_special

```
AENV=PROD
ASUID=B,98aae443-91e6-4a1f-897e-e9a914079443-tom
```

testcmd.cfg

```
TRAINING=http://localhost:8080/getWrapper?
QA=http://localhost:8080/getWrapper?
PROD=http://localhost:8080/getWrapper?
```

testcmd.bat

```
@echo off

echo %0
echo %1
type %1
echo "**"

for /F "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (%1) do set %%G=%%H

echo "(a)"
echo AENV=%AENV%
echo ASUID=%ASUID%
echo "**"

for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (C:\handle-special\testcmd.cfg) do set %%G=%%H

echo "(b)"
echo PROD=%PROD%
echo QA=%QA%
echo TRAINING=%TRAINING%
echo "**"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (%AENV%) do set CHOICE=!%%i!
set CHOICE=%CHOICE%SUID=%ASUID%

echo "(c)"
echo "%CHOICE%"
echo "**"

@pause
```

---

Doing:  testcmd.cmd test.handle_special on the command line produces (works).

```
testcmd.cmd
test.handle_special
AENV=PROD
ASUID=B,98aae443-91e6-4a1f-897e-e9a914079443-tom
"**"
"(a)"
AENV=PROD
ASUID=B,98aae443-91e6-4a1f-897e-e9a914079443-tom
"**"
"(b)"
PROD=http://localhost:8080/getWrapper?
QA=http://localhost:8080/getWrapper?
TRAINING=http://localhost:8080/getWrapper?
"**"
"(c)"
"http://localhost:8080/getWrapper?SUID=B,98aae443-91e6-4a1f-897e-e9a914079443-tom"
"**"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Making an association for test.handle_special in explorer and clicking on test.handle_special does not work, produces output below.

```
"C:\handle-special\testcmd.cmd"
"C:\handle-special\test.handle_special"
AENV=PROD
ASUID=B,98aae443-91e6-4a1f-897e-e9a914079443-tom
"**"
"(a)"
AENV=
ASUID=
"**"
"(b)"
PROD=http://localhost:8080/getWrapper?
QA=http://localhost:8080/getWrapper?
TRAINING=http://localhost:8080/getWrapper?
"**"
"(c)"
"SUID="
"**"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If I replace %1 to the name of the file at the first for loop in the source it works, clicking in explorer works.

Any clues to what wrong?

Comment: I don't get what the problem is here?

Comment: It gets the file path.  I can "type/cat" the file ok.

However 

"for /F "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (%1) do set %%G=%%H"

does not set the environment vars like it does on the command lines

See output at (a) from both command line and windows explorer invocation.